# The instance of entity type 'Unidad' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm from Argentina sorry for my English. i'm having this error with an enum that i changed to a class for mapping reasons.

```
public enum UnidadEnum{
  Gramos,
  Unidad,
  CN
}
```

And this is the class to map:

```
public class Unidad
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int IdUnidad{ get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    private Unidad(UnidadEnum @elem)
    {
        IdUnidad = (int)@elem;
        nombre = @elem.ToString();
    }

    protected Unidad() { }

    public static implicit operator Unidad(UnidadEnum @enum) => new Unidad(@enum);

    public static implicit operator UnidadEnum(Unidad u) => (UnidadEnum)u.IdUnidad;
    }
```

Seed in my dbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Unidad>().HasData(UnidadEnum.CN, UnidadEnum.Unidad, UnidadEnum.Gramos);
```

And the reference to Unidad in my Alimento Class:

```
 [Table("Alimento")]
 public class Alimento
  { 
    public int AlimentoId;

   [Column("nombre", TypeName="nvarchar(100")]
   public String nombre { get; set; }
   public virtual Unidad Unidad { get; set; }
   public int IdUnidad { get; set; }
}
```

When i want to add a new Comida with Alimentos witch contains the same Unidad (gramos) the error says

The instance of entity type 'Unidad' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdUnidad'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I am not explicitly adding those instances of Unidad each time i want to add a Comida, so EF is adding a new instance of Gramos each time and not using or updating the same one. I dont know how to fix it. or indicate to EF to use the seed only.